# Standard Normal Distribution Help

Tags: normal-distribution

The question is:
Let X be normally distributed with a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 6.
Calculate the value x such that P(x<X<14) = 0.4329.

The correct answer in the memo is given as:
[image: Answer]

I understand up to the point of P(Z < Zx) = 0.3146, but I don't understand the jump to the next step Zx = -0.4828. My original answer was (x-10)/6 = 0.3146 -> x=11.8876, but it seems that it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\Phi$ as
$\Phi(z) := P(Z \leq z),$
and note, that
$$\Phi(z_x) = 0.3146...$$
and thus we get that
$$z_x = \Phi^{-1}(0.3146) = -0.4828...$$
The function $\Phi^{-1}$ is refered to as the *quantile function* or as the *inverse CDF* for the standard normal distribution and it is implemented in most statistical software.